# How to get order data in magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.2, sales-order

How get all orders data in custom page in magento2

```
$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
 foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
 print_r($orderDatamodel1->getData());

 }
```

Nothing displaying. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working for me.

```
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();

    foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){

       echo '<pre>'; print_r($orderDatamodel1->getData());

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue but when I added

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in top of the page, I got below error.

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2621440000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes)
```

You can try below code

```
$orders = $obj->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->setPageSize(10) // only get 10 products 
    ->setCurPage(1);

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    print_r($order->getData());
}
echo "</pre>";
```

This is same method you are using to print data with filter and it is working fine.

There are 2 solutions, you can increase memory limit or select fields that you want in your collection.

In addition, use the **$order->debug()** method instead of **$order->getData()**. This will prevent memory leaks.

Comment: In addition, use the `$order->debug()` method instead of `$order->getData()`. This will prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks simonthesorcerer, i have add your comment in my answer

Answer (score -1):

Use `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection` instead of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` and remember to set the area code:

```
$appState = $objectManager->get("Magento\Framework\App\State")->setAreaCode("frontend");
$orders   = $objectManager->create("Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection");

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    print_r($order->getData());
}
```